# Receiving HTTP Error 500 when submitting a form to a php file

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my HTML file:

```
<div class="col-md-12 justify-center">
            <form action="login.php" method="post">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="inline-style">Username:</p>
                    <input class="float-right" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="inline-style">Password:</p>
                    <input class="float-right" type="text" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 justify-center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

It uses a post method and it's action is to login.php, the php file below. I'm trying to take in the username and password and send the data to ANOTHER php file. It hits the first php file and breaks, but I can't figure out why. 
Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$login = $_POST['login'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

$_SESSION['username'] = $login;
$_SESSION['passwd'] = $passwd;

$goto = 'Location: ./SelectStudents.php';
header($goto);
```

?>

Comment: A 500 error will put some log in the error_log.  What is it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to view the error log. I'm new to this

Comment: Nevermind. I had some other issues to resolve, but a big issue was that I didn't have permissions properly set up for that file! Thanks!